# C# How to insert XPathnavigator into XPathnavigator

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

Let's say I have the following XML file

```
<root></root>
```

and the following file

```
<child>
    <more-childeren> </more-childeren>
</child>
```

How do I insert the second file into the first file to create the following file:

```
<root>
    <child>
        <more-childeren> </more-childeren>
    </child>
</root>
```

I am receiving the second file as a XPathNavigator. What would be the fastest way to insert the XPathNavigator into the XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with XPathNavigators over editable tree structures like `XmlDocument/XmlNode` then use the `AppendChild` method taking an XPathNavigator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.appendchild?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_XPath_XPathNavigator_AppendChild_System_Xml_XPath_XPathNavigator_. That is at least the most convenient and API supported way, "the fastest" is a different criteria you would need to test.

A simple example working for me with .NET framework is

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(@"<root></root>");

            XPathNavigator nav = doc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator();

            XPathDocument doc2;
            using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(@"<child>
    <more-childeren> </more-childeren>
</child>")))
            {
                doc2 = new XPathDocument(xr);
            }


            XPathNavigator nav2 = doc2.CreateNavigator();
            nav2.MoveToFirstChild();

            nav.AppendChild(nav2);

            doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

The call `nav2.MoveToFirstChild();` seems to be crucial to not get the exception you mention in the comments.

Comment: When I use the appendChild method I get a Operation is not valid due to the current position of the navigator error. I get this error even when I use the MoveToRoot() beforehand

Comment: @Jiren, see whether the example in the edit helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try following xml linq :

```
           string xml1 = "<root></root>";
            string xml2 = "<child><more-childeren> </more-childeren></child>";

            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Parse(xml1);

            XElement root = doc1.Root;
            root.Add(XElement.Parse(xml2));
```